How to remove incorrect red background for the correct code?
In modern Perl the concept of function signature was introduced. I looks like this:
# old style:
sub my_sub {
    my $param = shift;
    # ...
}

# new style:
sub my_sub ($param) {
    # ...
}

When I use the function signatures vim incorrectly colourises the background inside the brackets with red, indicating that the code is incorrect:
=cut
sub get_all_days($self, $tour_id) {
}


I used the following function to find the current highlight groups for the text:
function! SynStack()
   if !exists("*synstack")
     return
   endif
   echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc

The groups are: ['perlSubPrototype', 'perlSubPrototypeError'].
How to fix Vim Perl parser to allow the function signatures, so they were not marked red?
Update
$ vim --version                                                                                                                                                        
   1 VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Mar 14 2024 09:05:11)                                                                                                                                    
   2 Included patches: 1-579, 1969, 580-1848, 4975, 5016, 5023, 5072, 2068, 1849-1854, 1857, 1855-1857, 1331, 1858, 1858-1859, 1873, 1860-1969, 1992, 1970-1992, 2010, 1993-2068, 2106, 2069-2106, 2108, 21     07-21                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   3 09, 2109-3995, 4563, 4646, 4774, 4895, 4899, 4901, 4919, 213, 1840, 1846-1847, 2110-2112, 2121   


Your "old/new" example a) is not highlighted as an error, and b) use the highlight groups perlSubDeclaration and perlSubName, here (Vim 9.1.0). Could you add the full output of $ vim --version to the body of your question? It looks like your syntax script is outdated.

@romainl Added the version. Seems, I need to upgrade the program.

I confirm the analysis of @romainl:

I can reproduce the problem with version of Vim below 8.2.4943
The problem seems to be solved with version of Vim 9.0.1


This is a duplicate of Correct syntax-highlighting on Subroutine Signatures in vim on Stack Overflow.
On older versions of Vim, you can set the variable perl_sub_signatures to 1. I’m not sure about the timeframe, but I’ve had it in my vimrc for a few years.

Thank you for pointing out. We can't mark duplicates on other SE sites. Providing cross-references as you did seems to be the best option.

Adding let perl_sub_signatures = 1 has removed the issue.
